# Failed to download package files. Check your internet connection

Tags: 12.04, wine, software-installation, playonlinux

I get this message any time I try to install PlayOnLinux from the software center. I know that my internet connection is fine.  i want to install PlayOnLinux for instal MicrosoftOffice but everytime want to download PlayOnLinux always appears a message "Failed to download package files. Check your internet connection".  just install PlayOnLinux cannot.  please give me a solution, so i can install PlayOnLinux???

Comment: Do a `sudo apt-get install playonlinux` in terminal and edit the question by copy-pasting the output here.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install `playonlinux` package through `apt-get`

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

Sometimes Software center fails to detect the internet connection but terminal does.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and type the following command:

> sudo apt-get update

Then restart Ubuntu Software Center and try installing PlayOnLinux again. This worked for me when I was facing the same issue while installing OpenJDK Java Runtime 7.